# Почему регулярное выражение /[a-z]\.[a-z]/g не выделяет вторую точку?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var str = "s.o.s";
str = str.replace(/([a-z])(\.)([a-z])/g, "$1$3"); // => "so.s"
```

Как получить "sos"?

Comment: Потому что первое совпадение захватывает букву `о` и для второго раза остается только `.s.` https://regex101.com/r/cQ0wH4/1

Comment: `Как получить "sos"?` - заменить точки на пустую строку?

Comment: @Visman Как получить "sos"?

Comment: KoVadim вам ответ уже дал.

Comment: @Visman Он спросил а не дал ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, как получить "sos" из "s.o.s"?

Comment: :) второй его вопрос является не вопросом, а утверждением.

Comment: @Visman Понял, я вам неправильно объяснил. Дело в том, что точки нужно удалить только между буквами и нигде больше не трогать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = ".ss....o.s.";
str = str.replace(/([a-z])\.+(?=[a-z])/gi, "$1");
alert(str);
```

До точек букву захватываем `([a-z])`, после точки нет `(?=[a-z])` и заменяем на захваченную букву `$1`.

Comment: Круто, а то я забыл про (?=)